# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/root/6.22.02-install/etc/notebook/migrated'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

*I am trying to open jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator and it is showing the following error. How to fix this? Helps will be highly appreciated!*

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/mohammad/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in
sys.exit(main())

File "/home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 268, in launch_instance

return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)

File "/home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)

File "", line 2, in initialize

File "/home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1761, in initialize

super(NotebookApp, self).initialize(argv)

File "", line 2, in initialize

File "/home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error

return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 244, in initialize

self.migrate_config()

File "/home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 169, in migrate_config

migrate()

File "/home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/migrate.py", line 247, in migrate

with open(os.path.join(env['jupyter_config'], 'migrated'), 'w') as f:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/root/6.22.02-install/etc/notebook/migrated'

Comment: I'm not sure since I've never done this, but since it's a permission error did you run it as sudo?

Comment: @aSaffary I tried everything! Finally the issue was automatically resolved by upgrading my Ubuntu to the latest version 21.10.